# Precision of up to 1 gram

Tags: puzzle, measurement

I know what precision means. But what does it mean to have a precision of up to 1 gram when talking about weighing machines? Does it mean if actual weight is 100 grams, it may show 99 grams, 100 next time and 101 the third time?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It means that the different values you would get, differs by atmost 1 gram.

Comment: Does it make sense if I am only measuring once?

Comment: Precision is a description of a level of measurement that yields consistent results when **repeated**. It is associated with the concept of "random error", a form of observational error that leads to measurable values being inconsistent when repeated. Hence it doen't make sense if you are measuring once.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is the difference between precision and accuracy

If you fired 100 arrows, high precision would mean each arrow falls on the same point, regardless of whether that point is the bullseye. In other words, it refers to the variability of the distribution

Accuracy, on the other hand, is whether the mean/center of that distribution is located around your intended target (the bullseye in the arrow example)

High precision + low accuracy would mean each arrow will be tightly grouped, but wont necessarily be grouped at the target

Low precision + high accuracy means your arrows will be distributed widely in an area, but the center of that area/distribution will be the intended target/bullseye

So in your weighing machine example, precision of 1 gram refers to variability of all your weighings. The lower the number, the more consistent the measurement